# C, using F commands in functions such as open()

Tags: c

Kind of a stupid question but seeing if its possible.

With the f commands you have for example, "w" which would be write to file, create new file if it doesn't exist.

With the O commands its a bit more complex, my research shows its: O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT

the o commands seems a bit too much to remember oppose to the f command. Is it "good coding" and possible to use W as the flag in an open function

Comment: Are you asking if you can use `"w"` as the mode in open? If so, no.

Comment: Well do not remember then and use a manual. One uses the stdio library (buffering etc) and the other is raw. Depends on the nature of the problem

Comment: It is "good coding" if it solves the stated problem. What is the stated problem btw, you never said. It sounds like you could just use fopen for this.

Comment: I got a lab for C at the end of the week. We get more marks using open, close and so forth oppose to using fopen. We don't get manuals....a bit stupid as I imagine in industries your allowed to use manuals

Comment: @Bobski- got the internet (hence posting the question here). i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/2/open - could print it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fopen function is defined in the ISO C standards (C99 7.19.5.3 for example). It is implemented in the C runtime library. As such all compliant C implementations, across all platforms, have to implement it.

The [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) function is defined in POSIX. It is specific to unix-like platforms.

When you call fopen on a unix-like, POSIX compliant platform, the runtime library inspects the arguments you are supplying and translates them into the corresponding arguments to the POSIX open function.

If you called fopen on another system, such as Windows, the runtime library would be calling a windows specific function to open the file - perhaps [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can't just supply the fopen arguments directly to POSIX open, or to Windows OpenFile for that matter. Those functions don't understand them.

In terms of "good programming" and which of these layers to use: in general, you should avoid directly calling OS system calls (such as the POSIX ones or the windows ones) unless you specifically need to for some reason. The reason is that your program will be more portable if you don't. It will be possible to compile it for any platform which has a compliant C compiler.

On the other hand, if you need some capability or option which is not available in the C Runtime libraries, then you should use the OS system calls.